# JSR-310 - parsing seconds fraction with variable length

Tags: java, java-time, datetime-parsing

Is there a way how to create JSR-310 formatter that is able to parse both following date/times with variable length of seconds fraction?

```
2015-05-07 13:20:22.276052
```

or

```
2015-05-07 13:20:22.276
```

Example code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter
= new java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append( java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") )
        .appendOptional( java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(".SSSSSS") )
        .toFormatter();
formatter.parse("2015-05-07 13:20:22.276052", LocalDateTime::from);
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-07 13:20:22.276052", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-07 13:20:22.276", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-07 13:20:22", formatter));

// output
2015-05-07T13:20:22.276052
2015-05-07T13:20:22.276
2015-05-07T13:20:22
```

The [answer by JiriS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103616/642706) is incorrect, as it uses `appendValue` whereas the correct way is to use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFraction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-boolean-) (which also handles the decimal point). The difference can be seen in the second system out, where [`appendValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValue-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-java.time.format.SignStyle-) incorrectly parses "2015-05-07T13:20:22.000276".

When parsing, [`LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) is a neater approach than using the formatter directly in most cases.

When using the [builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), take advantage of [`appendPattern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) and [`optionalStart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalStart--) to keep things neat.

Comment: Here you recommend using `LocalDateTime.parse` rather than using the formatter directly. Yet the doc for [`DateTimeFormatter.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-) says just the opposite: “Most applications should use this method for parsing.” … `LocalDateTime dt = parser.parse(str, LocalDateTime::from);`

Comment: I see the confusion. The phrase "Most applications should use this method for parsing" is wrt the other parse methods in `DateTimeFormatter`. It wasn't intended as a comparison against the `parse()` methods on classes like `LocalDate`. Thus my answer is correct, users should prefer `LocalDate.parse` to `DateTimeFormatter.parse`.

Comment: Is there a way to create such a formatter with **only** a pattern string?

Comment: No. Patterns are a subset of the possible formatters.

Comment: FYI to people seeing this years after it was written - that `appendFraction` signature does not appear to be in the latest couple of releases (at least on Maven Central, 2.9.9+). I couldn't find any alternative that worked for microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107522/10819573) is written by the architect of [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) and is the most elegant way to solve this problem. My answer shows an alternative way to solve this problem.

This solution leverages a feature of `DateTimeFormatter` that allows specifying optional units using square brackets.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]]",
                Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "2015-05-07 13:20:22.123456789",
                "2015-05-07 13:20:22.276052",
                "2015-05-07 13:20:22.276",
                "2015-05-07 13:20:22"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter)));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2015-05-07T13:20:22.123456789
2015-05-07T13:20:22.276052
2015-05-07T13:20:22.276
2015-05-07T13:20:22
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

And this one works

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter
= new java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append( java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") )
        .appendOptional(
                new java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendLiteral('.')
                    .appendValue( ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 1, 6, SignStyle.NOT_NEGATIVE).toFormatter())
        .toFormatter();
```

Comment: This Answer’s use of `appendValue` does not work in all cases. See the [Answer by JodaStephen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30107522/642706) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing fails with a datetime without any ":" characters:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, false)
            .toFormatter();
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("20150507132022123", formatter));
```

Edit: it was `appendFraction()` which expects `"."` character.