# Jackson: parse custom offset date time

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have a model which has a timestamp property:

```
class Model {
    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
}
```

The format of the timestamp is as following:

```
2017-09-17 13:45:42.710576+02
```

`OffsetDateTime` is unable to parse this:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "2017-09-17 13:45:42.710576+02": Text '2017-09-17 13:45:42.710576+02' could not be parsed at index 10

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You must tell Jackson in what format the date is. Basically, you have `year-month-day` followed by `hour:minute:second.microseconds` and the offset with 2 digits (`+02`). So your pattern will be:

```
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSx")
private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
```

Take a look at [all the date/time patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for a more detailed explanation.

---

If you want to preserve the same offset (`+02`) in the `OffsetDateTime`, don't forget to adjust the [`DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` option](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE) to `false`.

If this option is set to `true` (in my tests), the result is converted to UTC (but it actually converts to whatever timezone is configured in Jackson):

> 2017-09-17T11:45:42.710576Z

If I set to `false`, the offset used in the input is preserved:

> 2017-09-17T13:45:42.710576+02:00

---

The code above works with exactly 6 digits after decimal point. But if this quantity varies, you can use optional patterns, delimited by `[]`.

Example: if the input can have 6 or 3 decimal digits, I can use `pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.[SSSSSS][SSS]x"`. The optional sections `[SSSSSS]` and `[SSS]` tells the parser to either consider 6 or 3 digits.

The problem with optional patterns is that, when serializing, it prints all the patterns (so it will print the fraction of second twice: with 6 **and** with 3 digits).

---

Another alternative is to create custom serializers and deserializers (by extending `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer`):

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public CustomDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(parser.getText(), this.formatter);
    }
}

public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public CustomSerializer(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(OffsetDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(value.format(this.formatter));
    }
}
```

Then you can register those in the `JavaTimeModule`. How to configure this will depend on the environment you're using (example: in Spring you can configure in the [xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring)). I'll just do it programatically as an example.

First I create the formatter, using a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    // optional fraction of seconds (from 0 to 9 digits)
    .optionalStart().appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true).optionalEnd()
    // offset
    .appendPattern("x")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

This formatter accepts an optional fraction of second with 0 to 9 digits. Then I use the custom classes above and register them in the `ObjectMapper`:

```
// set formatter in the module and register in object mapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
module.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new CustomSerializer(formatter));
module.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new CustomDeserializer(formatter));
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

I also remove the `@JsonFormat` annotation from the field:

```
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
```

And now it accepts values like `2017-09-17 13:45:42+02` (no fraction of seconds) and `2017-09-17 13:45:42.71014+02` (5 decimal digits). It can parse from 0 to 9 decimal digits (9 is the maximum supported by the API), and it prints exactly the same quantity when serializing.

---

The alternative above is very flexible as it allows to set the formatter in the custom classes. But it also sets the serialization and deserialization for all `OffsetDateTime` fields.

If you don't want that, you can also create a class with a fixed formatter:

```
static class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter = // create formatter as above

    // deserialize method is the same
}

static class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter = // create formatter as above

    // serialize method is the same
}
```

Then, you can add those to only the fields you want, using the annotations `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize`:

```
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
```

With this, you don't need to register the custom serializers in the module, and only the annotated field will use the custom classes (the other `OffsetDateTime` fields will use the default settings).

Comment: Interesting, I did not know you can define the date format like this. Should I use a `OffsetDateTime` of `ZonedDateTime` for this?

Comment: @KwersT If you have only the offset +02, I suggest OffsetDateTime. If there's a timezone name (such as Europe/London) and Daylight Saving Time rules, then use a ZonedDateTime

Comment: I am getting a similar exception now on a 'similar' date time. Should I make some fields optional? `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type 'java.time.OffsetDateTime' from String '2017-09-17 14:23:11.319+02': Text '2017-09-17 14:23:11.319+02' could not be parsed at index 20`

Comment: I know you can do as in`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103167/jsr-310-parsing-seconds-fraction-with-variable-length, but I don't know how it should look like string-wise.

Comment: @KwersT It would be something like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.[SSS][SSSSSS]x` - the brackets delimiters an optional pattern, so this accepts 3 or 6 digits. I'm not sure if the 6 digits pattern should come first (sometimes the order matters). Sorry but I just left home and can't properly test it

Comment: I will start experimenting! Thanks again.

Comment: @KwersT I confirmed that the pattern must be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.[SSSSSS][SSS]x`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @KwersT I also added more insights to deal with variable-length fields.

Comment: `.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)` made my day.