# Offset lost for OffsetDateTime with Spring Boot REST Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson, offsetdatetime

I am using java `OffsetDateTime` to store time both on the client and server side.
When I am sending the time information to the server, the local date time part looks like:
`"2021-06-15T15:43:50"` and the offset is `+02:00` (Central European Summer Time).
However, when the time reaches my spring boot REST Service, it is deserialized as:
`"2021-06-15T13:43:50"` with NO offset.
Both the client AND the server are on the same host in central europe (my developper machine).

the field that is being serialized looks like this:

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
private OffsetDateTime lastWriteTime;

Why do I have the zero offset on the server side? How can I have the "local" offset on the server side, too?

Comment: The deserialized time is exactly the same as the serialized time.  The only difference is the time zone; the deserialized time is in UTC (i.e. no offset)

Comment: I realised that. I would like it to be deserialized to the OffsetDateTime with the offset representing the time zone.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps; take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263773/jackson-parse-custom-offset-date-time

Comment: This Question could use an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Replace `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` with `@JsonSerialize(using = OffsetDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = OffsetDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")` and let me know if it works.