# How to use jackson to parse RFC3339 timestamp with variable number of second fractions

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, jackson, rfc3339

I'm trying to parse timestamps in the RFC3339 format in a JSON-string using Jackson. How do I allow for the variable amount of decimal places after the seconds?

For the JSON file

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-07-02T13:00:34.836+02:00"
}
```

I've deserialized it with the class

```java
public abstract class Attribute {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    public Date timestamp;
}
```

and an `ObjectMapper` with the JavaTimeModule:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Attribute.class);
```

This works fine. However, it should also work for `"timestamp": "2019-07-02T13:00:34+02:00"` and `"timestamp": "2019-07-02T13:00:34.090909090+02:00"`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103167/jsr-310-parsing-seconds-fraction-with-variable-length) showing how to parse such strings with a `DateTimeFormatter`, but as far as I can tell, `@JsonFormat` only takes a `SimpleDateFormat` string, which do not have support for variable amounts of second decimals.

Removing the `pattern`-property all together, so the annotation becomes

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
```

allows me to parse the incoming dates, but also accepts non-RFC3339 timestamps like `1990-01-01T12:53:01-0110` (missing a colon in the timezone).

Comment: I haven't got the experience, but I would expect that if you change from the outdated `Date` to the modern `OffsetDateTime` and use jackson-modules-java8 (please search), it then will work out of the box.

Comment: FYI, that input string is actually in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. RFC 3339 is but a self-declared “profile” of ISO 8601. Unfortunately, rather than adding value, RFC 3339 actually contradicts the original standard with needless changes. I suggest sticking with ISO 8601 and avoiding RFC 3339 entirely. The *java.time* classes support ISO 8601.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) is registered in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), simply use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead of [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html). There's no need for [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html).

See the example below:

```java
@Data
public class Foo {
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
}
```

```java
String json =
        "{\n" +
        "  \"timestamp\": \"2019-07-02T13:00:34.090909090+02:00\"\n" +
        "}\n";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

Comment: While this fails on special leap-second cases like `1990-12-31T23:59:60Z` (from [the RFC3339 spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.8), it succeeds and fails correctly in all my other test, so I'm accepting it. Thank you!