# Unable to parse optional microseconds in localTime

Tags: java, datetime

I am receiving timestamp in format : HHmmss followed by milleseconds and microseconds.Microseconds after the '.' are optional

For example: "timestamp ":"152656375.489991" is 15:26:56:375.489991.
Below code is throwing exceptions:

```
final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      .appendPattern("HHmmssSSS")
      .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
      .toFormatter();
LocalTime.parse(dateTime,FORMATTER);
```

Can someone please help me with DateTimeformatter to get LocalTime in java.

Here is the stacktrace from the exception from the code above:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '152656375.489991' could not be parsed: Conflict found: NanoOfSecond 375000000 differs from NanoOfSecond 489991000 while resolving  MicroOfSecond
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1959)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1894)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:463)
    at com.ajax.so.Test.main(Test.java:31)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: NanoOfSecond 375000000 differs from NanoOfSecond 489991000 while resolving  MicroOfSecond
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.updateCheckConflict(Parsed.java:329)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.resolveTimeFields(Parsed.java:462)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.resolveFields(Parsed.java:267)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.resolve(Parsed.java:253)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeParseContext.toResolved(DateTimeParseContext.java:331)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1994)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103167/jsr-310-parsing-seconds-fraction-with-variable-length

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the exception you are getting there, as the code looks correct to me. Also share the exact string value dateTime is initialised with.

Comment: Are there always exactly 6 digits after the point if there are any? Or could the number of digits vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options, depending on the possible variations in the strings you need to parse.

**1. Modify the string so you need no formatter**

```
    String timestampString = "152656375.489991";
    timestampString = timestampString.replaceFirst(
            "^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(?:\\.(\\d*))?$", "$1:$2:$3.$4$5");
    System.out.println(timestampString);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timestampString);
    System.out.println(time);
```

The output from this snippet is:

> 15:26:56.375489991

The `replaceFirst()` call modifies your string into `15:26:56.375489991`, the default format for `LocalTime` (ISO 8601) so it can be parsed without any explicit formatter. For this I am using a regular expression that may not be too readable. `(…)` enclose groups that I use as `$1`, `$2`, etc., in the replacement string. `(?:…)` denotes a non-capturing group, that is, cannot be used in the replacement string. I put a `?` after it to specify that this group is optional in the original string.

This solution accepts from 1 through 6 decimals after the point and also no fractional part at all.

**2. Use a simpler string modification and a formatter**

I want to modify the string so I can use this formatter:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter fullParser
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss.[SSSSSSSSS][SSS]");
```

This requires the point to be after the seconds rather than after the milliseoncds. So move it three places to the left:

```
    timestampString = timestampString.replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(?:\\.|$)", ".$1");
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timestampString, fullParser);
```

> 15:26:56.375489991

Again I am using a non-capturing group, this time to say that after the (captured) group of three digits must come either a dot or the end of the string.

**3. The same with a more flexible parser**

The formatter above specifies that there must be either 9 or 3 digits after the decimal point, which may be too rigid. If you want to accept something in between too, a builder can build a more flexible formatter:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter fullParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("HHmmss")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 3, 9, true)
        .toFormatter();
```

I think that this would be my favourite approach, again depending on the exact requirements.

**4. Parse only a part of the string**

> There is no problem so big and awful that it cannot simply be run away
>   from (Linus in *Peanuts*, from memory)

If you can live without the microseconds, ignore them:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter partialParser
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssSSS");
```

To parse only a the part of the string up to the point using this formatter:

```
    TemporalAccessor parsed
            = partialParser.parse(timestampString, new ParsePosition(0));
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(parsed);
```

> 15:26:56.375

As you can see it has ignored the part from the decimal point, which I wouldn’t find too satisfactory.

**What went wrong in your code?**

Your 6 digits after the decimal point denote *nanoseconds*. Microseconds would have been only 3 decimals after the milliseconds. To use `appendFraction()` to parse these you would have needed a `TemporalUnit` of *nano of millisecond*. The `ChronoUnit` enum offers nano of day and nano of second, but not nano of milli. `TemporalUnit` is an interface, so in theory we could develop our own nano of milli class for the purpose. I tried to develop a class implementing `TemporalUnit` once, but gave up, I couldn’t get it to work.

**Links**

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Regular expressions in Java - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)