# Issue with parsing date time using ZonedDateTime and DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-time

I am having two different results from these two blocks even though the input date/time to parse is the same

```
public class DateTimeFormatterUtilsTest 
{
    private static final String ISO_DATETIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";;
    private static final String ISO_DATETIME_TO_PARSE = "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z";
    private static final long TARGET_EPOCH_TIME = 1196676930000L;

    @Test
    public void testDateTimeFormatterUtils()  
    {
        ZoneId targetZoneid = TimeUtils.getZoneId(TIMEZONE.PST);    
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(targetZoneid);
        long epochTime = parseDateTime(ISO_DATETIME_TO_PARSE, formatter);       
        assertTrue(epochTime == TARGET_EPOCH_TIME);
        
        
        // specify custom pattern       
        DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISO_DATETIME_PATTERN).withZone(targetZoneid);
        epochTime = parseDateTime(ISO_DATETIME_TO_PARSE, formatter1);
        assertTrue(epochTime == TARGET_EPOCH_TIME);

    }
    
    public long parseDateTime(final String dateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter formatter)
    {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
        System.out.println("parsed zoned date time" + zonedDateTime);
        
        Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
        long epochTime = instant.toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println("Epoch time for" + ISO_DATETIME_TO_PARSE + "is " + epochTime);
        return epochTime;
    }   
}
```

When I am using  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT I get the correct epoch time which is 1196676930000, however, when I am usin the .ofPattern method to create the DateTimeFormatter I am getting 1196705730000. Not sure why?

As you can see, the difference is 28 800 000 milliseconds or exactly 8 hours.

Comment: Related and similar: [How do I get an Instant object with the timestamp 48962-08-06T23:16:59.000Z in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843844/how-do-i-get-an-instant-object-with-the-timestamp-48962-08-06t231659-000z-in-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never put quote marks around the `Z`** in a date-time formatting pattern.

## `Z` means `+00:00`

The `Z` is a standard abbreviation for an offset of zero. Pronounced “Zulu” per aviation/military convention.

Yuor quotes treat the `Z` as meaningless string literal, preventing semantic interpretation. The `Z` carries vital information, meaning “an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds”. But your `'Z'` parsing pattern ignores that info.

This:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

… should be:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

By ignoring that offset, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly when you parsed as a `ZonedDateTime`. Hence your correct but unexpected results.

## `Instant`, not `ZonedDateTime`

Your input has no indication of time zone. So `ZonedDateTime` is not called for here.

Instead, parse as an `Instant`.

```
Instant.parse( "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z" )
```

If you want to see that moment through the lens of a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Terminology

Quick review of terms:

- **UTC** is the temporal prime meridian. In the old days this was the time kept at the [Royal Observatory in Greenwich, London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Observatory%2C_Greenwich).
- An **offset** is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC.
- A **time zone** is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

Comment: one question though does not this time "2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z" mean it is in UTC time zone (because it has Z in it?)

Comment: @bluemountain Yes, the `Z` means an offset from UTC of zero. But UTC is not really a time zone. UTC is the temporal prime meridian that defines the offsets used by time zones.

Comment: @user16320675 See the terminology section I added.

Comment: @user16320675 Yes. And as the point in time defining the offsets of time zones, UTC is a temporal prime meridian, the point at which all other time is kept. (Well, much time is kept, but not all. Other meridians exist, such as a point in Paris used by some French protocols.) In brief, UTC is the new GMT.

Comment: @user16320675 No, UTC is not a line drawn on the globe. You keep missing my use of the adjective *temporal*, a "temporal prime meridian". Programmers writing business apps really don't care about atomic clocks, leap seconds, navigation, and the BIPM. That's my audience here, not engineers doing rocket science with GPS/Galileo systems.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" did not work, however when I try "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX" it was able to recognize the current zone of the input and was able to parse the date time 2007-12-03T10:15:30.000Z. thank you all for the help.

Comment: the main learning is NOT to use 'Z' while parsing date time, try to use the letters from this table (like yyyy) https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html to really preserve the zone information while parsing.